# Result of a failed delivery of futures contract

Tags: trading, futures

I am curious about, what if the seller couldn't deliver the physical product of a futures contract? Will there be any penalty or something like that?

Comment: Relevant: [What happens to farmers' futures contracts if a natural disaster destroys their crops?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/53229/)

Comment: Yes, The second one did. Thanks! @Flux